# Store shipping details not captured

Tags: expresso-store

I'm troubleshooting with the example store templates that are supplied. In the store settings, I have the Default Shipping Address set to none. Still, when I submit the address as different for shipping and billing, the Shipping Details are listed as "Same as Billing Details" on the checkout3 template.

Thanks if anyone can help.

Comment: Make sure you are clearing your cart every time you make a template or setting change to Store to make sure the most current details are pulled.

Comment: Also what version of Store and EE?

Comment: I'm on the latest version of everything. Thanks for the tip about clearing, I still didn't get this to work. I solved this by just showing the shipping address no matter what.